# placing view on screen Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am loading pdf from url with PDF view. However, the PDF view covers the entire screen. This is why the Segment Controller disappears. PDF View should appear under the Segment Controller. What should I do to make it appear below the segment, not the full screen?

```
class PDFController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

  func fillWithYORUM() {
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                      let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
                      pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
                            self.view.addSubview(pdfView)
                                pdfView.autoScales = true
                     let postURL = URL(string: self.pdfLink)
                    if postURL != nil {

                      pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: postURL!)
                      print("postURL", postURL as Any)
                    }
                    else {
                    }
                  } else {
                  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set view bounds here which is full screen

```
let pdfView = PDFView(frame: self.view.bounds)
```

but you need either

```
let pdfView = PDFView(frame:self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy:segmentControl.frame.maxY)))
```

or

```
view.addSubview(pdfView)
pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  pdfView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segment.bottomAnchor,constant:20.0),
  pdfView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
  pdfView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
  pdfView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
])
```

Comment: Thanks. Error : Value of type 'UISegmentedControl' has no member 'maxY'

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to `frame` instead of `bounds`,

```
PDFView(frame: self.view.frame)
```

else update the position of `Y axis` with the `segmentControl` max height

```
PDFView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: segmentControl.frame.maxY, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - segmentControl.frame.height))
```

Comment: Thanks. Error : Value of type 'UISegmentedControl' has no member 'maxY'